# Перегрузить метод или сделать параметр необязательным?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг, solid

Есть вот такой сервисный класс для работы c файловым репозиторием:

```
public interface IFileService
{
    int AddFile(int repositoryId, Stream stream, string fileName, string userName);
}

public class FileService : IFileService
{
    #region Dependencies

    private readonly MyDbContext context;

    #endregion

    public FileService(MyDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int AddFile(int repositoryId, Stream stream, string fileName, string userName)
    {
        int fileId;

        //...

        return fileId;
    }
}
```

До сих клиентом класса `FileService` являлся верхний слой - контроллеры. Но теперь в ходе расширения продукта появился другой сервис, который в своей работе использует данный класс:

```
public interface IReportService
{
    int AddReport(Stream reportFileStream, string userName);
}

public class ReportService : IReportService
{
    #region Fields

    private const int ReportRepositoryId = 1;

    #endregion

    #region Dependencies

    private readonly MyDbContext context;
    private readonly IFileService fileService;

    #endregion

    public ReportService(MyDbContext context, IFileService fileService)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.fileService = fileService;
    }

    public int AddReport(Stream reportFileStream, string userName)
    {
        int reportId;

        //...
        var fileId = fileService.AddFile(ReportRepositoryId, reportFileStream, null, userName);

        return reportId;
    }
}
```

Как вы наверно заметили, в методе `ReportService.AddReport()` я в качестве параметра `userName` метода `fileService.AddFile()` передал `null` для наглядности. *Этот код конечно работать не будет, т.к. данный параметр для `fileService.AddFile()` обязателен*. Это имя файла в итоге сохраняется в базе данных, там это поле тоже обязательно.

**ПРОБЛЕМА**: Классу `ReportService` не нужно имя файла, в то время как для других клиентов класса `FileService` важно знать имя файла на стороне клиента. Но в данном случае я не хотел бы лишний раз "тащить" его.

**ЧТО НЕОБХОДИМО:** Необходимо сделать редизайн, чтобы `FileService` позволял добавлять файлы без аргумента `fileName`.

**МОИ РАЗМЫШЛЕНИЯ ПО ЭТОМУ ПОВОДУ:**

Я вижу два пути развития событий:

*0) Прежде всего конечно теперь в соответствующем объекте БД сделать поле `fileName is nullable`.*

**1)** Просто перегрузить метод

```
public interface IFileService
{
    int AddFile(int repositoryId, Stream stream, string fileName, string userName);
    int AddFile(int repositoryId, Stream stream, string userName);
}
```

и конечно аккуратно убрать дублирующий код.

**2)** Оставить как есть

```
public interface IFileService
{
    int AddFile(int repositoryId, Stream stream, string fileName, string userName);
}
```

и в самой реализации разрешить `fileName = null`, т.е. убрать валидацию на `null`.

---

### Вопрос

Так как лучше поступить?

Comment: Писать полноценный ответ - лень. Посмотрите на метод с точки зрения стороннего разработчика. Откуда ему знать реализацию, как ему понять, обязательный параметр или нет? Первый вариант в этом плане в разы удобнее, т.к. явно дает вариант работы без параметра.

Comment: не перезагрузка методов, а *перегрузка*

Comment: поддерживаю первый вариант (делаю только так), так как нет явных NULL в передаваемых параметрах, а значит код будет чище. Ну и добавление новых параметров будет не через переписывание существующих методов, а добавление новое реализации через переопределение методов.